# How to Post new order using shopify API

Tags: php, api, shopify

I've tried to create new order using a test from postman or ARC and it's work. But when I did from my php code I cannot Post neither Get orders (I can get products for example).

This is my code Class.Shopify.php

```
<?php 
     public function call($method, $path, $params=array())
{
    $baseurl = "https://{$this->shop_domain}/";
//var_dump($this->shop_domain);  

    $url = $baseurl.ltrim($path, '/');
    $query = in_array($method, array('GET','DELETE')) ? $params : array();
    $payload = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? json_encode($params) : array();
    $request_headers = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", 'Expect:') : array();

    // add auth headers
    $request_headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: ' . $this->token;

    $response = $this->curlHttpApiRequest($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers);
//var_dump($response);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

    if (isset($response['errors']) or ($this->last_response_headers['http_status_code'] >= 400))
        throw new ShopifyApiException($method, $path, $params, $this->last_response_headers, $response);

    return (is_array($response) and (count($response) > 0)) ? array_shift($response) : $response;
}
private function curlHttpApiRequest($method, $url, $query='', $payload='', $request_headers=array())
{
    $url = $this->curlAppendQuery($url, $query);
    //echo $url.' '.$payload;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
/*var_dump($ch);
            var_dump($method);
            var_dump($payload);
            var_dump($request_headers);*/

            $this->curlSetopts($ch, $method, $payload, $request_headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //var_dump($response);
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($errno) throw new ShopifyCurlException($error, $errno);
    list($message_headers, $message_body) = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $response, 2);
    $this->last_response_headers = $this->curlParseHeaders($message_headers);

    return $message_body;
}

private function curlAppendQuery($url, $query)
{
    if (empty($query)) return $url;
    if (is_array($query)) return "$url?".http_build_query($query);
    else return "$url?$query";
}

private function curlSetopts($ch, $method, $payload, $request_headers)
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    /*WHEN CODE DEPLOY TO LIVE SERVER, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER MUST BE TRUE*/
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ohShopify-php-api-client');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    if (!empty($request_headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

    if ($method != 'GET' && !empty($payload))
    {
        if (is_array($payload)) $payload = http_build_query($payload);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    }
}
?>
```

a part of my file to post order.php

```
$credential = $qdb->fetch();
//var_dump($credential);

//$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$mail = $credential['mail'];
$url =  $credential['site'];
$key = $credential['key'];
$token = $credential['token'];
$country = $credential['name'];
$id_country = $credential['id_country'];
ob_start();
//where Shopify api key and shopify secret are the credentials for the orders private app
$shop = new  ShopifyClient($url, $credential['token'], SHOPIFY_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_SECRET);

$orderData = array('order' => array(
'line_items' => array(
    array(
        'variant_id' => 30781726924,
        'quantity' => 1
    )
)));
$product = $shop->call('POST', "/admin/orders.json", $orderData);
var_dump($product);
$content = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents('update-pr.txt', $content);
?>
```

As I said I can get product but no orders and can't post orders.
I have orders in private app in "read and write".
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi! And your call method doesn't report any error? What about the reply you get - what's in it?

Comment: no, I checked my logs, and the file update-pr.txt does not update when I put post, but with get products I receive all products in the file. I don't kw how I could catch the response error as output in the same file txt.

Comment: But I see you commented out `var_dump($response);` in the cal method... What did it output when it wasn't commented?

Comment: I forgot it. let me check again.

Comment: I receive this "{"errors":"[API] This action requires write_orders scope."}" but I have yet define('SHOPIFY_SCOPE','write_orders'); in the file

Comment: any idea please how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the message in your logs, it seems you do not have write access to the order entity.

When you [ask users for permissions](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth#asking-for-permission), during the app installation, you need to specify all the permissions you think your app will need.

The authorize URL will look something like:

```
https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={api_key}&scope={scopes}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&state={nonce}&grant_options[]={option}
```

where *scope* will be, in your case, "read_products,write_products, read_orders,write_orders"

Just defining the constant in your PHP file will not be enough - the merchant, on whose store your app is installed, needs to grant you permission to do what you want to do.

Note also that you can't change those permissions on an installed app, either. You will have to first uninstall the app, make sure your code asks for the right permissions, and then re-install the app with the new permissions.

You'll see which permissions your app is asking for on the app authorization screen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you're right. I have a doubt, how can I get the private app password? I've tried using  `$password = $this->is_private_app ? $this->secret : md5($this->secret.$this->token);
$baseurl = "https://{$this->api_key}:$password@{$this->shop_domain}/";` but I cannot retreive the password I have in private app and the secret is not.

Comment: I use `$this->secret` that is the private app password. I print the `$url` output and is the same one I use in postman where is work but from the plugin I still receive this error [API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question... If you look at your `ShopifyClient` class, there should be a method in there to generate an authorization url. This should be where you start...

Comment: It was the token, I've sent the call including the token in the header and doing test in postman I've seen that I should send it without token and it's work. Big thanks @MacPrawn.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!